# Loading data from Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery while adding additional columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to load data from a parquet file in google cloud storage to Bigquery. While loading I also want to add couple of extra columns to the table which are not present in the source file like insert_time_stamp and source_file_name. After doing some research I found these options -

1. Create a temporary table linked to file in GCS and then load the data from the temporary table along with additional columns to the final Bigquery table.
2. Load the data from parquet file to pandas dataframe, add the extra two columns and then use pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq or client.load_table_from_dataframe options to load data to Bigquery table.
3. Load the data from parquet file to a staging table(by this I mean a normal table) in Bigquery and then use this table to create the final table as - **"insert into final_table select *,current_timestamp as insert_time_stamp, <file_name> as source_file_name from staging_table"**. And then finally dropping the staging table.

If the number of rows from the source file are in millions, what would be the best approach to take?

Comment: I wonder how 1 and 3 options are different.

Comment: @Jaytiger The difference is that in the first method I would be creating external temporary tables, thereby querying directly from cloud storage (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables). While in the 3rd option I would be loading the data from cloud storage to a native table in bigquery and then reading data from this table to a second native table in bigquery as mentioned in the post. After reading the data, I will have to drop the first table.

Comment: I see, thanks for the kind explanation. What I usually do for a similar problem is, like option 1, to create external table and import it into native storage table directly  applying simple transformation logic. Depending on the transform logic, if it's complicated or need to be joined with existing native table, It might be better to load raw data into a native staging table and transform it, which is your option 3, I guess.
(And I think you may already know, you can use `_FILE_NAME` pseudo column if you need a `source_file_name` for the final table.)

Comment: @Jaytiger, Yes, I am using _FILE_NAME pseudo column to get the file name. However, this can only be used when reading data from external tables. Is there any way to get the source file name if we are loading the data directly to a BigQuery native table?